# cutting video with ffmpeg gives no image

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to cut videos I get from a IPTV add-on in Kodi. The original video can be watched with VLC, Mplayer, xine, etc, but after being copied there is no image. According to mediainfo there is a video stream but nothing can be seen.
The command I use is:

`ffmpeg -y -i test-1.mpeg  -scodec copy -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0 -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:10.000 test-1-cut.mpeg`

I suppose there is something wrong with the original videos recorded by kodi, but they give no problem with any player. A short example video is this one:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0WC80aT-4WrSDNENzhxRUxkOXc

The output with the `-report` option is this one (it is too long to be copied here, sorry)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0WC80aT-4WrbF9DUWpfOXlzUkU

Could someone help me to fix this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been changing the filename of the output file to .ts. The command is then:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test-1.mpeg  -scodec copy -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0 -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:10.000 test-1-cut.ts
```

The .ts file is playable from initial time.

I do not know why it works. This solution was suggested by the developer of the kodi add-on I was using.